# Changing position of labels in ggcorrplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggcorrplot

I want to shift the y axis labels in the `ggcorrplot()` output in a way that they are placed adjacent to each circle on the right-hand side. Is this possible? I tried using `+theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = ...)`. I want a similar output as the plots returned by the `corrplot()` package.

```
library(ggcorrplot)
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
corr<-cor(mtcars)
cortest<-cor_pmat(mtcars, sig.level = 0.05)
ggcorrplot(
  corr,
  p.mat = cortest,
  hc.order = F,
  method = "circle",
  type = "lower",
  outline.color = "black",
  legend.title = "",
  lab = TRUE,
  lab_size = 2.5,
  ggtheme = ggplot2::theme_void,
  colors = c("#6D9EC1", "white", "#E46726")
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with `ggcorrplot::ggcorrplot`. I think you won't get around manually plotting the correlation matrix with some lower level functions

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you're requesting but one way to address the white space issue is to move the y-axis to the other side.

```
library(ggcorrplot)
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
corr<-cor(mtcars)
cortest<-cor_pmat(mtcars, sig.level = 0.05)
ggcorrplot(
    corr,
    p.mat = cortest,
    hc.order = F,
    method = "circle",
    type = "lower",
    outline.color = "black",
    legend.title = "",
    lab = TRUE,
    lab_size = 2.5,
    ggtheme = ggplot2::theme_void,
    colors = c("#6D9EC1", "white", "#E46726")
  ) + scale_y_discrete(position='right')
```

[image]